# @Html.CheckBoxFor Funciona no GET, mas não no POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho o seguinte model:

```
public class MEUViewModel
    {
        public List<Obj1> Obj1s { get; set; }
        public List<Obj2> Obj2s { get; set; }
        public int IDMeu { get; set; }
        public int IDMeu2 { get; set; }

        public bool Chk1 { get; set; }
        public bool Chk2 { get; set; }
        public bool Chk3 { get; set; }
        public bool Chk4 { get; set; }
    }
```

Meu método POST é de assinatura básica:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult METODOPOST(MEUViewModel viewModel)
        {
          ...
        }
```

Em minha View eu tenho o seguinte Razor, um para cada bool do viewmodel:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Chk1)
```

Eles estão dentro de um `BeginForm()`, não vou colocar o código todo porque ao fazer o `submit` ele cai no `POST` normalmente.

Ele gera o seguinte HTML:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo Chk1 é obrigatório." id="Chk1" name="Chk1" type="checkbox" value="true">
<input name="Chk1" type="hidden" value="false">
```

Ao fazer o POST todos os quatro bools vem False, independentes de estarem marcados ou não.

- As duas propriedades que tem um list de objetos vem com o bind normal.
- Os IDs (ints) vem com os binds normais.
- **Se eu colocar true em alguma das quatro propriedades no método GET ele vai gerar o HTML com o checkbox marcado.**

---

**ATUALIZAÇÃO COM SOLUÇÃO TEMPORÁRIA**

Depois de tentar muitas coisas:
- Coloquei o HTMl na mão, conforme o link que o Marconi mandou
- Tentei o JS do Paulo
- Tentei a resposta do Warleson

e nada de funcionar, agradeço a todos.

O que eu fiz para funcionar de forma temporária foi mudar a assinatura do metodo:

```
[HttpPost]
            public ActionResult METODOPOST(MEUViewModel viewModel, bool Chk1, bool Chk2, bool Chk3, bool Chk4)
            {
```

E jogo o valor das variáveis no model. Não é bonito, mas foi o que funcionou.
Vou deixar a pergunta em aberto porque acredito que um `@Html.CheckBoxFor` em uma estrutura tão básica deveria funcionar de forma mais simples, quem sabe alguém reposta alguma solução melhor.

Comment: Veja está [pergunta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14730746/getting-checkbox-value-in-asp-net-mvc-4) ela está muito parecida rs.

Comment: Chuto que o que está acontecendo é : Está indo o valor do input hidden

Comment: @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Chk1) Já tentou assim?

Comment: Já tentei também @PauloHDSousa . Mesmo resultado.

Comment: Antes de dar o submit, faça isso if ($('[name="Chk1"]:checked').length > 0)
    $('[name="Chk1"]:hidden').val(true);

Comment: Fiz o JS, mandei um Alert para ver se o valor foi alterado, ele foi alterado, mas chega falta no controller. @PauloHDSousa

Answer (score 1):

Passa o valor para o Controller

```
 @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Chk1,new { Chk1  = true} )
```

Por padrão ele já passa como false, então quando estiver marcado ele envia True

Comment: Esse segundo parametro não seria para fazer o render? [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ee830434(v=vs.118).aspx). PS: Tentei fazer, não pegou true não.

Answer (score 0):

Algumas alternativas

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Chk1,new { Chk1  = true} )
```

ou

```
 @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Chk1, htmlAttributes: new { Chk1 = true })
```

ou

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Chk1,true)
```

Controlle

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult METODOPOST(MEUViewModel viewModel)
            {
```

Estrutura do CheckBox:

```
   public static MvcHtmlString CheckBoxFor<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> expression, object htmlAttributes);


  public static MvcHtmlString CheckBoxFor<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> expression, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes);
```